# Why are my variables not incrementing by 1

Tags: swift, variables

I am making a quiz app and everytime the user presses button 1 or button 2 the variables "currentQuestion" and "currentAnswer" increment by 1 to give the next question in the dictionary.

Except when I run my app and use a label to test the counter it sometimes doubles when I choose the correct answer. I have spent a long time trying to resolve the issue but I cannot understand it!

Also I understand my code is probably terrible and any suggestions on how to improve it would be great!

Thanks

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// Program Outlets

@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var incorrectLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

// Program Variables

var questionStorage =

[
    "1" : "Red is a four letter word. True or False?" ,
    "2" : "Cat is a three letter word. True or False?",
    "3" : "Dog is a five letter word. True or False",
    "4" : "I Smell Like a wet noodle!",
    "5" : "The ultimate smell awaits"

]

// True = 1 & False = 0

var questionAnswers =

[

    "1" : "0",
    "2" : "1",
    "3" : "0",
    "4" : "1",
    "5" : "0"


]

var incorrectQuestions: [String] = []
var incorrectQuestionCount = 0
var questionCount = 1
var currentQuestion = 1
var currentAnswer = 1





// Program Functions

// Question Generation Function

func Questions() {


    var currentQuestionString = String(currentQuestion)
    var currentAnswerString = String(currentAnswer)


    // Question Selection Variables

    var question = questionStorage[currentQuestionString]
    var answer = questionAnswers[currentAnswerString]

    // Question Counter Variables


    //countLabel.text = currentQuestionString

    // Question Generation Code

    questionLabel.text = question
    countLabel.text = answer
    testLabel.text = currentAnswerString

}

// Check for quiz completion

func checkFinish() {
    if questionCount == 5 {
        questionLabel.text = "Test Finished"

    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a       nib.

    // Button Setup

    button1.layer.cornerRadius = 30;
    button1.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    button2.layer.cornerRadius = 30;
    button2.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    // Begin Program

    Questions()
}



// True & False Button Actions

@IBAction func button1Press(sender: AnyObject) {

    if countLabel.text == "1" { // correct

        incorrectQuestions.append(questionLabel.text!)
        ++currentQuestion
        ++currentAnswer
        Questions()
        checkFinish()
        ++questionCount
        ++incorrectQuestionCount
    }

    if countLabel.text == "0" { // incorrect

        incorrectQuestions.append(questionLabel.text!)
        ++currentQuestion
        ++currentAnswer
        Questions()
        checkFinish()
        ++questionCount
        ++incorrectQuestionCount
    }
}

@IBAction func button2Press(sender: AnyObject) {

    if countLabel.text == "0" { // correct

        incorrectQuestions.append(questionLabel.text!)
        ++currentQuestion
        ++currentAnswer
        Questions()
        checkFinish()
        ++questionCount
        ++incorrectQuestionCount
    }
    if countLabel.text == "1" { // incorrect
        incorrectQuestions.append(questionLabel.text!)
        ++currentQuestion
        ++currentAnswer
        Questions()
        checkFinish()
        ++questionCount
        ++incorrectQuestionCount
    }
}





override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: Please consider reducing the amount of code provided here so that we can quickly find the source of the problem.

Comment: Hello! Sorry as I am new I am not entirely sure which parts you would need to see exactly, so I just postd the whole thing !

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger and stepping through the program to see what is happening?

Comment: The idea of reducing the amount of code to put here is also that it might help you to find the answer by yourself

Comment: button1Press and button2Press for result 0 and 1 does exactly the same thing?

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the quick responses. I am going through the debugger now very slowly, as I`m still learning to use it.

I made button1Press and button2Press results the same to try and debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In `button1Press`, between

```
if countLabel.text == "1"
```

and

```
if countLabel.text == "0"
```

the call to `Questions` may change the value of `countLabel.text`.
It it's set to `"0"`, you will execute the second conditional as well as the first.

Replace `if countLabel.text == "0"` with

```
else
```

and the same thing with `button2Press`, of course.